# version control routine on Android for data ?

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a routine that checks the version of files on the sd card. The app essentially downloads a list of files on the sd card. The files on the server are prone to changes in the future.

How do I manage to check if the app is using the latest file. I thought doing it by forcing the user to reinstall the app and using SharedPrerfernces to store the version of each file, but then when the app is reinstalled the SharedPreferences will be deleted.

Any other way that you can suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [lastModified()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29) method to determine the last time you got the files in question and then check to see if they're older than the ones on the server.

Comment: seems like there is similar method to check a file on the server something like this: URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
              con.connect(); and then con.getLastModified(); could I use this method !!

Comment: One caveat, I'd use the HttpURLConneciton. It's the one that is being actively developed on by the android team. It also has a getLastModified() method though, so no worries!

Comment: what's the difference between HttpURLConnection and URLConnection !?

Comment: HttpURLConnection is more efficient and faster on android.